# Is a Frechet space separable, if its dual is?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

It is known, and not too difficult to prove that if a dual of a normed space is separable, it is separable itself. Does the same hold for Frechet spaces?

(By the dual I mean the dual endowed with the strong topology.)

Comment: Did you try to transfer the usual proof in case of a normed vector space?

Comment: @gerw The proof that I know relies on the norm heavily: you should be able to choose "small" functionals and "large" vectors. If you know a transferable proof, could you please give a reference?

Comment: Do you consider the weak*-topology or the strong topology on the dual space? Note that $F^*$ with the strong dual is in general not metrizable. In fact, this happens only if $F$ is already normable, i.e. a banach space. In this situation we can apply the result for banach spaces.

Comment: @p4sch I mean the strong topology. I know that $F^*$ is not always metrizable, but in my specific case it is separable, and I want to conclude that $F$ is then separable too, without assuming that $F$ is normed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Fréchet space $X$ is an inverse limit of a sequence of Banach spaces since the topology of $X$ is induced by a countable family of seminorms $\|\cdot\|_n$ (thay may easily be arranged to be decreasing).

Suppose that the strong dual of $X$ is separable. Set $X_n = X / \{x\colon \|x\|_n = 0\}$. Each $X_n$ is a Banach space and $X$ admits a natural surjection onto each $X_n$ and so $X^*$ is an inductive limit of $X_n^*$s. In particular, each $X_n^*$ sits homeomorphically in $X^*$, which we assume is separable. Hence all $X_n$s have separable duals so they are separable themselves (here we use the fact that a metrisable subspace of a separable topological vector space is separable; see Corollary 4 [here](https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/axioms/axioms-08-00003/article_deploy/axioms-08-00003.pdf) for a more general statement).

Being an inverse limit is nothing but being a certain subspace of the Cartesian product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n$, which is metrisable and separable, hence so is every subspace thereof. Consequently, $X$ is separable.

Answer (score 1):

I think so (no books at hand for a reference). All we need for the normed proof to go through, is some sort of Hahn-Banach theorem that gives us enough functionals to works with. And Fréchet spaces have enough functionals.

Comment: we also need to choose "small" functionals and "large" vectors (at least in the proof that I know). Perhaps you could elaborate?